# Importing OBJ and exporting as FBX leads to reimported FBX having wrong texture mapping on faces, is there a solution for blender 3?

Tags: texturing, faces, .fbx, obj, vector-mapping

Issue is reproducible in Blender 3 while in Blender 4 it seems to be fixed, but I am working using older Blender so would be good to find a fix compatible with that.

The issue is that importing OBJ and exporting as FBX leads to reimported FBX having wrong texture mapping on faces (see above) even if geometry stood same as in OBJ. Importing FBX in Blender 3 shows problem, but not in Blender 4. So they seem to be importing differently, but touched some import settings and didn't find a way to get it to work on Blender 3.

Any ideas how to fix this in blender 3 please ?
[image]